# "skip.header.line.count"="1" does not work in Hive in SparkSession

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to load a CSV data into Hive table using SparkSession.
I want to skip the header data while loading into hive table  and setting tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1") is also not working.

I am using the following code.

```
import java.io.File

import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession,Row,SaveMode}

case class Record(key: Int, value: String)

val warehouseLocation=new File("spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath

val spark=SparkSession.builder().appName("Apache Spark Book Crossing Analysis").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir",warehouseLocation).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
import spark.sql
//sql("set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=false")
sql("drop table if exists BookTemp")
sql ("create table BookTemp(ISBN int,BookTitle String,BookAuthor String ,YearOfPublication int,Publisher String,ImageURLS String,ImageURLM String,ImageURLL String)row format delimited fields terminated by ';' ")
sql("alter table BookTemp set TBLPROPERTIES("skip.header.line.count"="1")")
 sql("load data local inpath 'BX-Books.csv'  into table BookTemp")
 sql("select * from BookTemp limit 5").show
```

Error in consol:

```
res55: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = []
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but '.' found.
sql("alter table BookTemp set TBLPROPERTIES("skip.header.line.count"="1")")

2019-02-20 22:48:09 WARN  LazyStruct:151 - Extra bytes detected at the end of the row! Ignoring similar problems.
+----+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|ISBN|           BookTitle|          BookAuthor|YearOfPublication|           Publisher|           ImageURLS|           ImageURLM|           ImageURLL|
+----+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|null|        "Book-Title"|       "Book-Author"|             null|         "Publisher"|       "Image-URL-S"|       "Image-URL-M"|       "Image-URL-L"|
|null|"Classical Mythol...|"Mark P. O. Morford"|             null|"Oxford Universit...|"http://images.am...|"http://images.am...|"http://images.am...|
|null|      "Clara Callan"|"Richard Bruce Wr...|             null|"HarperFlamingo C...|"http://images.am...|"http://images.am...|"http://images.am...|
|null|"Decision in Norm...|      "Carlo D'Este"|             null|   "HarperPerennial"|"http://images.am...|"http://images.am...|"http://images.am...|
|null|"Flu: The Story o...|  "Gina Bari Kolata"|             null|"Farrar Straus Gi...|"http://images.am...|"http://images.am...|"http://images.am...|
+----+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

AS shown in the result , I want to skip the first row of data

Comment: What solution you find to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using sql then the workaround is to add filter to the sql:

```
sql("select * from BookTemp limit 5 where BookTitle!='Book-Title'").show
```

This Jira is related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11374

Also read this: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/14638 - you can use CSV Reader option:

```
spark.read.option("header","true").csv("/data").show
```

Or remove header using shell before loading:

```
file="myfile.csv"
tail -n +2 "$file" > "$file.tmp" && mv "$file.tmp" "$file"
```

Comment: Is there not any option where I can ignore the header while loading the data into the hive table from csv.
I am asking this because my requirement is to load the data into hive table first

Comment: @vikashpatwa Remove header using shell before loading

Comment: @vikaspatwa you already have a filtered dataframe to work with (the where clause). Other alternative is to write back the filtered dataframe and then read the same.

Comment: @leftjoin If i remove using shell command then header will not be in csv file. But will it be in Hive table? I want header in hive but also getting header in spark dataframe.

Comment: @milky_way If you want header to be present than deleting using shell is not an option.  The error you getting is because of nested double-quotes which break the string. Try either shielding nested double-quotes with double backslash: `\\"`  or try to use single-quotes instead of nested double-quotes:  `sql("alter table BookTemp set TBLPROPERTIES('skip.header.line.count'='1')")` . But it will not affect spark/ dataframe loaded from Hive table. To skip header in dataframe use one of other recipes: filter in sql or read.option

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative I was trying using spark sql to convert the CSV with Header to parquet

val df = spark.sql("select * from schema.table")

df.coalesce(1).write.options(Map("header"->"true","compression"->"snappy")).mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet()

Comment: The other alternative if header=true also doesn't work is to filter the header row in the SQL Query itself. Faced this issue when in case there are multiple files with header (in hdfs/s3) under the table -- val df = spark.sql("select * from schema.table where COLUMN_NAME="COLUMN_NAME")