# Extra header is coming while reading hive external table from spark?

Tags: hive, pyspark, cloudera-cdh

I create a external table in hive and put csv on the HDFS location which is pointed by external table. While checking in Hue the table output is coming in right format, but when i try to read the same table using spark then the data frame has first row same as header i.e header is duplicated two times.

cdh version : Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.13.1

DDL

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `dummy`(
  name string,
  age string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE    
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'  
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (  
  'quoteChar'='\"',     
  'separatorChar'=',')  
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT   
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'    
OUTPUTFORMAT    
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'  
LOCATION    
  '/tmp/dummy'  
TBLPROPERTIES ( 
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='false',  
  'numFiles'='1',   
  'numRows'='-1',   
  'rawDataSize'='-1',   
  'skip.header.line.count'='1')
```

csv

```
name,age
abc,10
```

Output in Hue

```
+----++----+
|name| age | 
+----++----+
|abc | 10  |
+----++----+
```

Output in spark

sparkSession.table('dummy').show()

```
+----++----+
|name| age | 
+----++----+
|name| age | 
+----++----+
|abc | 10  |
+----++----+
```

Expected Output from Spark

```
+----++----+
|name| age | 
+----++----+
|abc | 10  |
+----++----+
```

Comment: Answered the same here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54792289/2700344 It was never accepted though

Comment: @leftjoin thanks for prompt reply